# android-How to border canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm making a circle canvas and I want to add a border to it .

```
final int color = 0xffa19774;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setDither(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
        sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);
```

How can I add a border around this canvas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw a border using `Paint.STYLE.STROKE`. You need to do two separate calls to drawCircle():

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399")); // set fill color
canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
    sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);

paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10); // set stroke width
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")); // set stroke color
canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
    sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw a border around a circle, you only need to draw two circles on to your canvas. Both circles have the same dimension however the circle below should have a stroke.

Also, to draw an image border, the circle below should be given a bigger radius than the one above.

```
   public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
            finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                    false);
        else
            finalBitmap = bitmap;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f, finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20); // set stroke width
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00")); // set stroke color
        canvas.drawCircle(finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f, finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);


        return output;
    }
```

The example above returns a bitmap circle image with a border.

This is the code to draw the stroke

```
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(20); // set stroke width
  paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00")); // set stroke color
  canvas.drawCircle(finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f, finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
```